# What is the meaning of 'this is not here'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the phrase "this is not here"? I saw this on a door in a John Lennon video and wonder if this is a Zen phrase or specific English usage.

Comment: This doesn't mean anything as it stands. But consider interpreting the sense more broadly: it could mean something like "this might as well not be here" (e.g. the door exists, but does not fulfil its purpose), or "this is not real" (e.g. the door seems to signify something which isn't really true or doesn't really exist). Incidentally, "This Is Not Here" is an exhibit of Yoko Ono.

Comment: How about also asking on SkepticsSE?  http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

I think it's a self-referential joke in the style of say Magritte's "Ceci n'est pas une pipe".

Answer (score 1):

I think it means "we are not living in this world; we are living in the world we want to live in, which is not here".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's some sort of paraphrase on the line "nothing is real" from Strawberry Fields Forever. It could literally mean "This is not here. You're not really looking at it." — as in, nothing around you is real, nothing is here. That's my take on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the fact that nothing really exists. All matter is 99.99999% empty space. Everything is just an illusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the literal sense, as the boy said to Neo in The Matrix, "There is no spoon." To understand this, you must also understand reality without limitations. Everything is made of atoms, 10% matter / 90% space. Our reality manifests our condition to be truth when it's in reality an illusion. If you are awake this will make more sense; if you are still in a walking coma from your reality, wake up.